# Python dnslib.server with edns support

Tags: python, dns

When using python dnslib.server example and trying make queries from bind9 server python dns server get these error's:

```
Mar  5 20:07:23 mx1 named[1868]: success resolving '85.31.199.1.domain.example/A' (in 'domain.example'?) after disabling EDNS
Mar  5 20:41:29 mx1 named[1868]: success resolving '141.36.123.190.domain.example/A' (in 'domain.example'?) after reducing the advertised EDNS UDP packet size to 512 octets
```

Any hint or solution how this can solve with python dnslib.server library ?

Answer (score 0):

EDNS is a specific feature of DNS nameservers, albeit not  a new one. But it needs specific support (code to handle it).

What you see is that bind9 as a client detects that the server it speaks too lacks EDNS support and hence fallback to some previous sane setup.

The changelog of your library has this:

> - 0.7 2012-10-20 Add initial EDNS0 support (untested)

and nothing after, so it does not look good.

The code source shows two promising classes:

- `EDNS0`
- `EDNSOption`

It seems to be used when parsing the record in `RR.parse` that the server uses, but it may be working or not, we can not judge since you do not show your code and how it uses the library.

So, in short, either the library has a problem and its EDNS code will need to be improved or there is some problem in your program using it.

The related question is why you use this library, is it just to experiment/learn or to really build a product on top of it? In the last case, depending on what you are doing, lack of EDNS support may create you problems (for example for DNSSEC).

Comment: Using this example to testing:
https://bitbucket.org/paulc/dnslib/src/d2c17b8b154de94deabd981dda84f65c1e084565/dnslib/fixedresolver.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

I trying build product, get dns request, then doing something with that ip and finally response pack record.

Comment: You will then have to change the resolve() method and read RFC6891: the server is supposed to reply with an OPT record too for EDNS. See point 6.1.1: "   If an OPT record is present in a received request, compliant responders MUST include an OPT record in their respective responses.". You have these bind warnings because bind send OPT records to your nameserver, which does not reply with OPT records.